# Loading related entities when dealing with Models and Collections from Backbone to Express / Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backbone.js, express, mongoose

I have a `UserService` object that is essentially a `Service` with additional configuration parameters and is attached to a `User`. In my View I would like to render a list of these `UserServices` however the model is formed as such:

```
UserService = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: { 
        id: 0, 
        user_id: 0, // This needs to reference the user object somehow 
        service_id: 0, // This needs to reference the service object somehow
        length: 216000, 
        price: 1000
    }
});
```

If I bind this model to the view, what is rendered ends up being the service_id instead of the parameter I need to render: `service.name`.

My questions are:

What should be stored in the `UserService` model at service? The full service object? Mongoose ID? Some other ID? (Please specify a suggestion)

Where should I get the information for this `service.name` / When should I pull the `Service` object to get that information? It would be nice to be able to do `service.name` in the view when rendering...

Is there a function to chain--upon loading the model, load related models that are needed?

Overall I just need an understanding of how related models work in Backbone / Express / Mongoose.

Any help is appreciated!

**Update:** After doing a bit of reading I have a couple different methods I can see:

1. Within the [constructor / initializer](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor) load the `Service` object into the `UserService` object based on the reference ID returned from the server.

My questions with that one then become... what is the reference ID? Where do I put the newly retrieved object into, possibly in place of the ID?

1. Use the toJSON method to return an asthetic version of the UserService where it retreives the `Service` object and would return an object with the service name in it's place:

   {
       id: ???, 
       service_name: "this was retrieved from the service object in the toJSON method", 
       length: "1 hour", // converted from within the toJSON method
       price: 10.00 // converted from cents to dollars in the toJSON method
   }

Or maybe a combination? Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

[Parse](http://parse.com) models handle loading related entities well, there is also [library called Backbone Relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) that can help with this.

Otherwise, my best recommendation is to store the object's ID and fetch the related entity upon success of fetching the first entity.

Anyone needing a code example just comment here and I'll see what I can come up with.